# R Markdown and htmlTable. How to generate html tables in a loop in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to create `htmlTables` from all the files in the given directory and display them in R markdown.

However when i try to use `htmlTable` in the `for` loop there is no output. Here is the code:

````
``{r }
path<-"~/wyniki stocks"

listFiles<-as.list(list.files(path))

for(file in listFiles){

################################  
 #Generating path to the current file 
path1<-paste(path,"/",file, sep="")
print(path1)

#############################
#Reading File
output<-read.dta(path1)


######################################
#html table
htmlTable(output[1:2,1:2])

}



print("Why are there no tables above?")


htmlTable(output[1:2,1:2])

```
````

output of the code:

[image]

The best solution I was able to come up with is, to write the output of the `htmlTable` into a List `htmlList` and diplay the Tables one by one using `asis_output()`. But this also does not work in a loop.

```
# Does not work, htmlList is a list  
htmlList[i]<-htmlTable(output[1:2,1:2]) 
for(i in 1:10)
asis_output(htmlList[i],meta='html')

#works
asis_output(htmlList[1],meta='html')
asis_output(htmlList[2],meta='html')
asis_output(htmlList[3],meta='html')
```

It may work if there are one or two tables. 
But I need it to work independently of the number of the files.

Here is also a reproducible example  :

```
# Preparing data

{r}
library(htmlTable)
library(knitr)
output <- matrix(1:4,
                 ncol=2,
                 dimnames = list(list("Row 1", "Row 2"),
                                 list("Column 1", "Column 2")))


# Part 1

{r}
htmlTable(output)


# Part 2
{r}
for(i in 1)
  htmlTable(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
for(i in 1)
  print(htmlTable(output))
```
````

I.e. wrap `htmlTable` within the `for` loop in `print`, and use the chunk option `results='asis'`, which writes raw HTML results (in this case) from R into the output document.

Comment: You could skip the `results='asis'` and use `knit_print` instead.